# How to map a JSON into POJO for rest Template in java?

Tags: java, json, resttemplate, hubspot

I have a JSON response coming from Hubspot API as following, I am having trouble to parse it into Java POJO for using with RestTemplate.
Since the Json reponse is not in form of json arrays,I am not able to create proper java classes.
Can someone please help?

The JSON response received is as following:

```
{
  "1": {
    "vid": 1,
    "canonical-vid": 1,
    "portal-id": 5017510,
    "is-contact": true,
    "profile-token": "AO_T-mOzMc0AQx3P50QBw3qJ09A30BWfeQu89iOhW5ADWb6-uIT7m37lYwSTk7ObLEYwwnpxGNM1x9rkivaT-abeu6MegOWO31EUpZ3b56hfFti61ewcGQvC-XocjM2fekCOtK5oyM1C",
    "profile-url": "https://app.hubspot.com/contacts/5017510/lists/public/contact/_AO_T-mOzMc0AQx3P50QBw3qJ09A30BWfeQu89iOhW5ADWb6-uIT7m37lYwSTk7ObLEYwwnpxGNM1x9rkivaT-abeu6MegOWO31EUpZ3b56hfFti61ewcGQvC-XocjM2fekCOtK5oyM1C/",
    "properties": {
      "firstname": {
        "value": "Cool"
      },
      "city": {
        "value": "Cambridge"
      },
      "createdate": {
        "value": "1539332326199"
      },
      "company": {
        "value": "HubSpot"
      },
      "state": {
        "value": "MA"
      },
      "email": {
        "value": "coolrobot@hubspot.com"
      },
      "website": {
        "value": "http://www.HubSpot.com"
      },
      "jobtitle": {
        "value": "Robot"
      },
      "lastmodifieddate": {
        "value": "1539332330206"
      },
      "lastname": {
        "value": "Robot (Sample Contact)"
      }
    }
  },
  "51": {
    "vid": 51,
    "canonical-vid": 51,
    "portal-id": 5017510,
    "is-contact": true,
    "profile-token": "AO_T-mNsLUnhG0QdyfV6D_JZhoqldgC_jYOZswkSrsgRW1uvUZpajXSjd-83OtQEdptpio0VAgtGD3_qIOe_4vnijJ8_q6traOskjw5A48d1RhghdFuqiDpgz7pRcuzTrMjsvWF5Oat3",
    "profile-url": "https://app.hubspot.com/contacts/5017510/lists/public/contact/_AO_T-mNsLUnhG0QdyfV6D_JZhoqldgC_jYOZswkSrsgRW1uvUZpajXSjd-83OtQEdptpio0VAgtGD3_qIOe_4vnijJ8_q6traOskjw5A48d1RhghdFuqiDpgz7pRcuzTrMjsvWF5Oat3/",
    "properties": {
      "firstname": {
        "value": "Brian"
      },
      "city": {
        "value": "Cambridge"
      },
      "createdate": {
        "value": "1539332326434"
      },
      "company": {
        "value": "HubSpot"
      },
      "state": {
        "value": "MA"
      },
      "email": {
        "value": "bh@hubspot.com"
      },
      "website": {
        "value": "http://www.HubSpot.com"
      },
      "jobtitle": {
        "value": "CEO"
      },
      "lastmodifieddate": {
        "value": "1539332334158"
      },
      "lastname": {
        "value": "Halligan (Sample Contact)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are Tools available, to assis creating a POJO from JSON. http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Answer (score 1):

See this link, http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ in it you pass the JSON and it mounts the POJO for you, however you want.

I tested with your JSON and generated perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jackson to convert JSON response into POJO class.
Sample code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
POJOClass pojoclassObj = mapper.readValue(jsonResponse, POJOClass.class);
```